Create a search bar in tableau to search a specific name and it be in the center of the sheet
NBA worksheet tableauI want to create a nba dashboard as a side project but I am stuck on getting the names to come to the center of the sheet and basically have the other names disappear while that name is selected to basically highlight the name.
I tried creating a filter first to try and have it come to the center while searching for a name but it only shows the name where it's at on the list and doesn't bring it to the center. I tried creating a parameter and calculated field for a search engine to try and hopefully fix it but that didn't work either so I was hoping someone here could help me figure it out. TY!

Filters filter, highlighters highlight. You can create dashboard actions to trigger "actions" on clicks or hover to hide or show certain elements of a dashboard... Can you provide a screenshot of what you tired/ or a paint png of your expected output?

I was only able to create a link since I'm still new here but you see how it is filled with all the names from the table. I would want to basically have it be blank until you search a name from the nba player you want to look up and bring it to the middle of the sheet.

Edit your [player name] filter to have nothing initially selected, rather than say "Use All", unselect all. This should clear your sheet of names and make it blank. Now when you type in the wildcard filter (as long as its set to contains) it will populate the matching results in your sheet as you type.
NOTE: these types of filters work best with extracted datasource connections.
As for centering your text, maybe just center align it, there are about 30 different ways to format text in Tableau, but from your picture, start by heading to the Text section of your Marks Pane, or right click the names in the sheet and choose format. Check out this link to the documentation for formatting navigation for more detailed info.
